# How do you remove isolated roads from a bigger network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, network-analyst, network, topology

I'm trying to perform an OD Cost Matrix calculation on a set of points using a road network from OpenStreetMap data. The network contains lots of roads that don't connect to the rest of the network. In the case where a point snaps to such a place on the network, it can't reach any other sample points.

How do I remove these sections of road? Or if that's not possible, how could I systematically identify those areas and connect them to the rest of the network?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to include a picture of what your data looks like?  Also, what version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using, and is your data stored in a file geodatabase or something else?

Comment: Disconnected line segments are difficult to spot in the vector model ArcGis uses; when ESRI was using coverages they were easy to find (DrawEnvironment Node Dangle). I have found disconnected end points using feature vertices to points with both end option and then event rendering to compile end counts. The unattached ends have a count of 1 I exported then joined to the lines - any that had both ends with a count of 1 are isolated. This will only work if the lines are planar (i.e. end-on-end).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution to this was kind of a kludge, but then I was doing a small class project working with a subset of one county's roads so the network wasn't that big and I didn't need to do it as a common task.  I just ran a service area analysis with the time set large enough that in theory everything should be reachable.  That highlighted everything that was connected, thereby showing what wasn't.  Some of them I added new connections because I needed to preserve those areas, others I simply selected and deleted the isolated roads from the dataset.

10.1 help has reference to a [Find Disconnected](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002r00000033000000) tool on the Utility Network Analyst Toolbar if you have access to that.

10.2.1 also has a new tool that might do what you want, if you have access to that version or higher: [Find Disconnected Features In Geometric Network (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000194000000)

Comment: Large enough time for service area solved my problem! thanks! +1

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a possibility to delete isolated lines from OSM data, too. Unfortunately, I have a huge amount of data. And having to deal with Network Datasets anyway, I just didnt want to examine Geometric Networks. But using Michaels suggestion worked, thank you very much! I had to change 2 things: First, I had to unsplit the lines in the beginning, so that I was been able to delete also isolated parts that consists of more than 1 feature line. Second, the last step consists of a query to the lines with a joinCount of 2 (istead of a iCount of 1). My data is preprocessed OSM data, stored in a file geodatabase. Here are the detailed steps:

1. Make a copy of the roads dataset -> roads_copy
2. Use "unsplit line" tool on roads_copy -> roads_unsplit
3. Use "feature vertices to points" tool on roads_unsplit (point type: both ends) -> roads_vert
4. Use "collect events with rendering" tool on roads_vert (quite time intensive) -> roads_collect (unattached ends get ICOUNT = 1)
5. Query roads_collect: "Select from roads_collect where ICOUNT = 1"
6. Export query result -> roads_icount1
7. Use "spatial join" tool to join roads_icount1 (= join features) to roads_unsplit (= target features); choose "one_to_one", "keep all target features" and "intersect" -> roads_join (isolated roads get Join_Count = 2)
8. Query roads_join: "Select from roads_join where Join_Count = 2"
9. Use "select layer by location" on original (not unsplitted!) roads; selecting features = roads_join, relationship = "share_a_line_segment_with", selection type = "new_selection"
10. Delete selected rows using "delete rows" tool

There you go. Maybe put it in a model. It seems a little complicated but leads to the desired result for me.

Comment: I followed AriJane's method and it worked, however, some false positives will be returned if line 'a' connects to the vertex of line 'b' (such as a T-intersection) and that vertex on line 'b' is not an end point. If the 'false positive' line is a bridge/overpass/underpass, all of the lines that intersect will also be deleted. For a dataset with ~185,000 line features @ step 2 above, the whole process (steps 2-10) took 14 minutes. The tool mentioned by Chris W, [found here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000194000000) is only available @ 10.2.1 and above.